# Matt black carbon bike

Tags: carbon

Just want to ask about the finish of matt black carbon bike. I bought a brand new specialized carbon bike. And the surfaces are like the images. I thought it’s kind of smudges or smears that could be left or made in assembling in the bike shop. When I asked them, they said it’s not any smear or smudges. They said they are the edges of layers of carbon meeting and on raw lacquered frames, These cross over points are then visible through the carbon. It sounds like it’s true. But when i see the frame, still doubt if it’s really what it has to be.

So want to hear anyone’s experience or any photos similar with mine to be assured.

Thanks

J

[image]

Comment: Matte finish is overly sensitive to (greasy) fingers or skin in general and accidental, unwanted polishing by rubbing on clothing, almost unavoidable when cycling.

Comment: There are care products available from the car care industry since many companies sell cars with matte finish. Shop around for these, unless your bike seller has specific products.

Answer (score 6):

It's the carbon weave visible through the matt lacquer. it's an attractive finish but not everyone loves it.

That is a UD weave rather than the easier-to-identify 3k, which looks like fabric.

[image]